# Access VMware based webserver from any computer via internet

Tags: virtual-machine, internet-connection, webserver, vmware-workstation

I have created a web server(ubuntu server OS), on my web-development machine, using VMware Workstation. Now I want that I could point my website's nameservers to this virtual machine servers & thus do testing. So I need this virtual machine to be able accessible remotely from any computer via internet.

What settings do I need to configure for that ?

---

My Guest OS is ubuntu server 11.04 & host is Win7

Answer (score 3):

There are a few different things you can do, however, if I take the most common thing people want to do...

If you mean that you are hosting websites/services inside the virtual machine, by far the easiest method you can do is to set up networking in "Bridged mode" so that each machine will be seen on the network like any other physical machine. Next, using your router, simply forward the ports you need (for example, 80) to the Virtual Machine's LAN address.

Then, simply set up an external dns entry that points to your public IP and you should be able to connect in from anywhere.

If I am wrong/you wanted to do something else, please let me know.

Comment: Thanks, could you let me know how do I find out the lan address of VM & configure the router settings ?

Comment: Once you set up bridged networking, the VM will act like any other machine on your network. It will either be a static ip that you set or be dynamically provided by your router... If it is Linux, at the command line, type "ifconfig", if you have a GUI, I am not sure the best way... As for your router, look for a setting called NAT, but, I can't really help you on that without knowing more - try taking a look at portforwarding.com where you may get some help there.

Comment: internet connection just went away completely from the virtual machine after I set it to bridged mode (changing from the default NAT mode in which case it was working).. On trying `ifconfig` it shows some weird eth0 inet6 address with some characters. I also tried portforwarding.com but seems this site has been removed(nothing except for ads)

Comment: any insights please ?

Comment: Do you have DHCP enabled on your router? and/or does your machine have a static IP? ... Is this in your house/local or have you purchased a server somewhere? And, did you run ifconfig on the VM or the host?

Comment: yes DCHP is enabled & lease interval period is 24 hours so I guess its dynamic IP.. it is at my home & I ran ipconfig/all on my host(win7) where I saw DCHP enabled for LAN..

Comment: I'm now able to successfully ping the host from VM & vice versa & internet is also working on VMs under bridged mode! :) Now could you please tell me how do I get a public IP for my VMs ?

Comment: The VMs will use your current internet IP (you can try going to www.whatismyip.com from any machine on the network)... you then need to log on to your router and basically forward a port from the outside IP to the internal one using something called NAT... take a look around your router and if you need any more help, please say.